# Value for latitude cannot be cast from String to Double in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, fetch, native

i have json

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "error": false,
  "driver": [
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Kevin",
      "lat": "-6.2616031",
      "lon": "106.8424822"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "jhon",
      "lat": "-6.20032449",
      "lon": "106.6372306"
    },
}
```

here I am capturing or retrieving json data and displaying it on maps
when i show i get an error problem which
is:

> Value for latitude cannot be cast from String to Double in
> react-native

where is the error ?
this is my code

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://example.com/myjson')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data: data.driver })
      })
      .catch(console.error)
   }

mapMarkers = () => {
        return this.state.data.map((driver) => <MapView.Marker
          key={driver.id}
          coordinate={{ "latitude": driver.lat, "longitude": driver.lon }}
          title={driver.name}
          description={driver.division}
        />)
      }

render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
            
            <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1, width: window.width }} //window pake Dimensions
            Region={{
                latitude: 106.8424822,
                longitude: -6.2616031,
                latitudeDelta: 70,
                longitudeDelta: 45
              }} >
            {this.mapMarkers()}
            </MapView>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The type of your latitude and longitude data in your JSON is string. You probably have to convert your latitude and longitude to double when passing them to Marker component's coordinate prop. So can you try this instead?

```
coordinate={{ "latitude": parseFloat(driver.lat), "longitude": parseFloat(driver.lon) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use lat or lng without Double quotation `""` in state

for example:

`"lat": -6.2616031,`

not `"lat": "-6.2616031",`

Answer (score 0):

The value passes to the latitude and longitude in mapview must not be in string format.

example:

`<MapView style={{width:100%,height:"100%}} initialRegion={{ latitude : 11.610400, longitute: 76.083000, latitudeDelta:0.003, longitudeDelta:0.003 }} />`